# Htaccess - redirect old URL to new that CONTAINS old URL (i.e. sub-directory)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Situation: need to redirect www.example.com/**widget-type** to www.example.com/**widget-category/widget-type**

Problem: using this:

```
RewriteRule ^.*(widget-type).*$ https://example.com/widget-category/widget-type/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

...generates a 500 error... as it should, since the destination URL contains the original string, so it just processes endlessly.

Using one of the several "redirect generators" produces either no effect, or a 500 sitewide.

Soo... what's the proper, working syntax for redirecting a URL to a new URL that contains an exact match of the old URL?

Answer (score 1):

Your rule can be a lot simpler:

```
RewriteRule ^(widget-type)$ /widget-category/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

That should only redirect for `/widget-type`.